# ubercart 2 with smtp - sending unformatted emails

Tags: 6, ubercart, emails

Recently I had to switch sending emails to be sent using smtp. https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp 
The problem is that all system emails are sent ok regarding formatting. All emails sent by ubercart are unforatted and basically unreadable.
Any idea how is it possible to fix that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried phpmailer module https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer and all messages (even created by ubercart) are displayed as formatted to end users.